# How to write Entity for two tables having foreign key and combination key

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

[37.1 User Schema](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/) shows two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `authorities` (
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `authority` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `ix_auth_username` (`username`,`authority`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_authorities_users` FOREIGN KEY (`username`) REFERENCES `users` (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `enabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**How to write Entity class so spring boot application would generate tables like above (entity describes the same as mysql schema)?**
I also tried it with generated entities but Authorities.java does not have primary key and after adding a Long-type id as its key, it throws `org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.example.spring.security.acl.Users, at table: authorities, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(users_by_username)]`

Users.java:

```
@Entity
public class Users {
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private Byte enabled;
    private Collection<Authorities> authoritiesByUsername;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "username", nullable = false, length = 50)
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false, length = 50)
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "enabled", nullable = false)
    public Byte getEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(Byte enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "usersByUsername")
    public Collection<Authorities> getAuthoritiesByUsername() {
        return authoritiesByUsername;
    }

    public void setAuthoritiesByUsername(Collection<Authorities> authoritiesByUsername) {
        this.authoritiesByUsername = authoritiesByUsername;
    }
}
```

Authorities.java:

```
@Entity
public class Authorities {

    private String authority;

    private Users usersByUsername;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "authority", nullable = false, length = 50)
    public String getAuthority() {
        return authority;
    }

    public void setAuthority(String authority) {
        this.authority = authority;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "username", referencedColumnName = "username", nullable = false)
    public Users getUsersByUsername() {
        return usersByUsername;
    }

    public void setUsersByUsername(Users usersByUsername) {
        this.usersByUsername = usersByUsername;
    }
```

Comment: It is not typical to do this with JPA, and in production applications you usually want to avoid automatic schema manipulations anyway. I suggest looking at Flyway (or Liquibase; both have Boot integration).

Comment: @chrylis but entities describe the tables should be able to write even if people do not generate tables from entities I guess. Now I cannot find a way to write entities that identify the tables.

Comment: Maybe *mappedBy* of *Users* should point to the *username* field.

Comment: Spring Security isn't using JPA at all.